# Zip lists of unequal size (more values than keys) to form a uniform dictornary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of strings:

```
keys = ["hostA", "hostB"]
values = ["element1", "element2", "element3", "element4", "element5"]
```

I want to combine these two lists into a dictionary(string, list), such that the length of the list for each string key is (almost) uniform.

The final results should be:

```
adict["hostA"] = ["element1", "element2"]
adict["hostB"] = ["element3", "element4", "element5"]
```

I tried `dict(zip(keys,values))` but this stopped zipping after the `keys` hit the end.

Comment: Does the length of the `key` and `values` lists vary? If so, what would the desired output be?

Comment: the length of `keys` and `values` does not vary during runtime. The desired output is given in my OP

Comment: So would you be happy to simply use slicing?

Comment: if it solves my problem, sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I wrote the ugliest list comprehension in my life:)

```
delim = len(keys)
dict([(key, values[index*delim:index*delim + delim]) if index < len(keys) -1 else (key, values[index*delim:]) for index, key in enumerate(keys)])
```

But if it ok to you you can write it as a normal loop, it will be much more nice.

This comprehension can handle more than two values in `keys` list

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit crazy but it works...

```
In [100]: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

In [101]: b = [100,200]

In [102]: dict(zip(b,[a[n*l:n*l+l]
               for l in [(lambda x,y:x+(1 if y else 0))(*divmod(len(a),len(b)))]
                   for n in range(len(b))]))
Out[102]: {100: [1, 2, 3, 4], 200: [5, 6, 7, 8]}

In [103]: b = [100,200,300]

In [104]: dict(zip(b,[a[n*l:n*l+l]
               for l in [(lambda x,y:x+(1 if y else 0))(*divmod(len(a),len(b)))]
                   for n in range(len(b))]))
Out[104]: {100: [1, 2, 3], 200: [4, 5, 6], 300: [7, 8]}

In [105]:
```

... because

- you can define AND use an anonymous function on the fly and
- you can unpack the tuple returned by `divmod` using the `*` operator.

The meaning of `x+(1 if y else 0)` is that the number of elements in each group is `len(a)/len(b)`  (the first item returned by `divmod`) unless the remainder (the second item returned) is not `0`, in which case you have to increment the number by one.